# Wordpress Visual composer - Call template from php file

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I have created a basic template in Visual Composer which mostly defines a layout of the page. Now I can select this template from "My templates" in VC.

However, what I really need is to call the template from a single_page.php file. Ensuring that end users can't change the layout via VC.

Is there any way how to do so? Via some VC API function or shortcode? Something like `[vc_template name="my_custom_layout"]`?

Thanks for any help,
Jakub

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
echo do_shortcode( "[vc_template name='my_custom_layout']", false );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not working... it seems that VC API syntax for template shortcode is not vc_template.

Comment: @JakubKašpar see this helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525669/how-to-get-visual-composer-page-through-rest-api